# Jest- JSDOM Pass HTML to JSDOM constructor in Jest when instantiate JSDOM

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, jsdom

Is there a way to pass HTML to the constructor in jest built-in JSDOM, like

```
const dom = new JSDOM('<!DOCTYPE html><p>Hello world</p>'); - in orginal JSDOM
```

I looked at Jest configure API, there are two **testEnvironment [string]** and **testEnvironmentOptions** for JSDOM, but it seems they can not satisfy my demand.

Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `JSDOM` instance gets created [here](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/7e1e3f8c3da1caddf113648f1a7d1db7ed365571/packages/jest-environment-jsdom/src/index.ts#L33-L39) with just `'<!DOCTYPE html>'`.

So initializing JSDOM with custom HTML isn't really possible with the built-in `JSDOM` instance created in `jest-environment-jsdom`.

---

You can, however, set `document.body` to whatever you want:

```
test('change document body', () => {
  document.body.innerHTML = '<p>Hello world</p>';
  expect(document.body.innerHTML).toBe('<p>Hello world</p>');  // Success!
});
```

---

...and you can always run in a `node` environment and create your own `JSDOM` instance:

```
/**
 * @jest-environment node
 */
const { JSDOM } = require("jsdom");
const { window } = new JSDOM('<!DOCTYPE html><p>Hello world</p>');
const { document } = window;

test('initialize JSDOM with custom HTML', () => {
  expect(document.body.innerHTML).toBe('<p>Hello world</p>');  // Success!
});
```